# How to get the value of a new AutoInc field value after Insert with TFDUpdateSQL

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

I am trying to access the newly-generated Auto Increment field value when using TFDUpdateSQL from, e.g., SQL Server.

The [Cached Updates sample](https://github.com/Embarcadero/RADStudio10.3Demos/tree/master/Object%20Pascal/Database/FireDAC/Samples/Comp%20Layer/TFDQuery/CachedUpdates/OnUpdateRecord) includes this as the Insert SQL:

```
INSERT INTO {id Products} (
  ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID,
  QuantityPerUnit, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock, UnitsOnOrder,
  ReorderLevel, Discontinued)
VALUES (
  :NEW_ProductName, :NEW_SupplierID,
  :NEW_CategoryID, :NEW_QuantityPerUnit, :NEW_UnitPrice,
  :NEW_UnitsInStock, :NEW_UnitsOnOrder, :NEW_ReorderLevel,
  :NEW_Discontinued
)
{IF MSSQL} select :NEW_ProductID = @@identity {FI}
{IF MSAcc} select @@identity as ProductID {FI}
{IF MySQL} select LAST_INSERT_ID() as ProductID {FI}
{IF IB} returning ProductID {into :NEW_ProductID} {FI}
{IF PG} returning ProductID {into :NEW_ProductID} {FI}
{IF SQLite}; select LAST_INSERT_ROWID() as ProductID {FI}
{IF Ora} returning ProductID into :NEW_ProductID {FI}
```

However, the sample does not use the `NEW_ProductID` result in code (or any other way I can determine), and the data table grid on the form does not reflect the new ProductID value that the SQL Server has generated.

I tried looking at the TField from the TFDQuery component, but that field component also does not have the new value in its NewValue property.

How can I access and use the new AutoInc value that was retrieved from @@identity from code?

Answer (score 1):

I did find a solution, at least for SQL Server.  It turns out that the InsertSQL generated by the TFDUpdateSQL component is different than the InsertSQL in the sample.  The generated code includes the `INSERT INTO` clause, followed by

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ProductID
```

If I use the original INSERT INTO clause, followed by that clause, then I am able to access the new AutoInc value within the OnUpdateRecord handler using a TField on the TFDQuery.
The new InsertSQL is

```
INSERT INTO {id Products} (
  ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, 
  QuantityPerUnit, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock, UnitsOnOrder, 
  ReorderLevel, Discontinued)
VALUES (
  :NEW_ProductName, :NEW_SupplierID, 
  :NEW_CategoryID, :NEW_QuantityPerUnit, :NEW_UnitPrice, 
  :NEW_UnitsInStock, :NEW_UnitsOnOrder, :NEW_ReorderLevel, 
  :NEW_Discontinued
)

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ProductID
```

I can then access the new ProductID AutoInc value within the OnUpdateRecord handler, after the usProducts.Apply() call, with

```
theIdField := qryProducts.FindField('ProductID');
theIdValue := theIdField.AsInteger;
```

That same code also allows access to the temporary (pre-insert) AutoInc value when used before the usProducts.Apply().

(note: I tried posting this on community.idera.com, but I could not get the reply to save)